# Deeplinks with Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I've had this problem since Angular 1 and was really hopefull that it would be solved in Angular 2: support fo deeplinks.  Both versions of Angular have a router which is meant to show completly different states of a page.  This works when its just 1 parameter at a time, but what happens when you have 20 different params you want to show for one page?  So here is an example of a deeplink I want to achieve:

`angular-app.com/#type=1&form=a&blah=blah&size=40`

Currently, I wrote my own service that basically has a set and get function that parses the window.location.hash to read the settings and also updaates it when a param has changed.  This works fine but it is written in pure javascript.  So I am wondering if there is a native way to do it with Angular2?

Comment: There are currently 3 completely different routers available for Angular2 (from the Angular team, two being deprecated) Any specific version you're interested in? The version that's supposed to stay is in alpha stage and it's not clear what features are already working. In the previous routes this worked to some degree. In the new router this will definitely work, perhaps it does already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a new router that came out a few days ago that is in `alpha` state as of 6/16/16, but it will be the new default router for Angular2. You can read more about it here: [Angular2 Router-3](http://victorsavkin.com/post/145672529346/angular-router)

You can install it with npm by the package: `@angular/router@3.0.0-alpha.3`

But one of the many new features it will have (that modern routers need, like you said) is deep-linking.

[Here's a plunkr example of it in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/ER0tf8fpGHZiuVWB7Q07?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! Will try it out and will report back!

Comment: Just keep in mind deep linking might not be fully finished yet :)

Comment: LOL thanks for the heads up.  If it is not, I will keep using my solution until they make it work.

Comment: Ok sorry for late reply but after working with the latest router, it gave me exactly what I needed!  To perform deeplink navigation from code I just call this:
this.router.navigate(['/blah'], {queryParams: {a: 'sdad', b: 'sdd'}});

Comment: great :) figured it would have it all in this newest one!